# Twists in elliptic curves.

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I was going over twists over elliptic curves. I came over this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381676/question-about-quadratic-twists-of-elliptic-curves). Which refers to this lecture [notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/EllipticCurves.pdf), on page $43$ in the second proof, the author mentioned

> For simplicity we are going to assume $char\ K \ne 2, 3$ and, in
> particular, that $E$ and $E′$
> can both be put in short Weierstrass form. So suppose we have:

> $E_1 : y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$, and

> $E_2 : y^2 = x^3 + A_1x + B_1$.

> Then if $j(E_1)\ =\ j(E_2)$, we have
> $\frac{A^3}
> {4A^2 + 27B^2}
> =
> \frac{A_1^3}
> {4A_1^3 + 27B_1^2
> .}$
> Clearing denominators and using $char\ K \ne 3$ we get

> $A^3B_1^2= A_1^3B^2$

I did not understand the last step, using cross-multiplication, we get $A^3(4A_1^2+27B_1^2)=A_1^3(4A^2+27B^2)$ from this how can we arrive at $A^3B_1^2= A_1^3B^2$

Also when $j(E_1)=1728, \implies A\ne 0,b=0 $, then do we have to take $u=(\frac{A}{A_1})^{1/4}$ Isn't all the curves with $B=0$ isomorphic?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have a typo in the denominator of $j(A,B)$: Citing Silverman, The Arithmetic of elliptic curves, we have $j(A,B) = 1728 (4 A^3)/(-16(4 A^3 + 27 B^2))$ (p.50)

Comment: Terms will cancel each other.

Comment: The typo is already in the lecture notes you have cited.